# C# - Make 4 radiobuttons change positions on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, random, radio-button

This is in **Windows Form Application**

The application looks like this:

```
RADIO1 text = 1
RADIO2 text = 2
RADIO3 text = 3
RADIO4 text = 3
```

When I press the button named`button1`, it will be something random like this:

```
RADIO2 text = 2
RADIO1 text = 1
RADIO4 text = 4
RADIO3 text = 3
```

I have tried something like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4"};

public void ShuffleText()
{
  var rand = new Random();
  var shuffledText = list.OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
  var radioButtons = new[]{radioButton1,radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4};

  for(int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length;i++)
  {
    radioButtons[i].Text = shuffledText[i];
  }
}
```

But, as you can see, this only shuffles the radioButton's text, and I don't want the buttons to change, because it's for a quiz I am creating, and I don't want the example answer on the top of radioButtons all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look more into your Location of your component instead of just the text property

EDIT;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4"};
List<int> Locations new List<int>{100,200,300,400};
var r1 = new RadioButton();
var r2 = new Radiobutton();
var r3 = new RadioButton();
var r4 = new RadioButton();

var buttons = new[]{r1,r2,r3,r4};

var rand = new Random();
var shuffledText = list.OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
var ShuffledButtons = Locations.OrderBy(x=> rand.Next(locations.Count)).ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length;i++)
{
    radioButtons[i].Text = shuffledText[i];
    radioButtons[i].Location.Y = shuffledButtons[i];
    radioButtons[i].Location.X = 50;
}
```

EDIT2: 
The previous code will randomize both your radiobuttons as your texts.

- RB1 = 1
- RB3 = 2
- RB2 = 4
- RB4 = 3

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic radio button on click of button and add control dynamically in parent control.

You also able to put table layout control above radio button and change cell position according to random generated number.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
List<Point> list = new List<Point>{radioButton1.Location,radioButton2.Location,radioButton3.Location,radioButton4.Location};
// Rest of the code remains the same
var shuffledLocation = list.OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length;i++)
   radioButtons[i].Location= shuffledLocation[i];
```